# How to set F4 to :NERDTree in vi?

Tags: vim

How do set F4 as a hotkey to :NERDTree ?

I want it available in normal mode and insert mode.

Or has any good suggest hotkey to nerdtree ?

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the help files on how to bind keys.

```
:help key-mapping
```

Try something like:

```
:nmap <silent> <F4> :NERDTree<CR>
```

For insert mode you do `:imap` instead.

Comment: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Comment: Since the OP specified insert and normal mode, `inoremap` and `nnoremap` should be used.